# How to vertically stack the results of a for loop to a 2D array?

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, vstack

I've trained the CNN model to classify the images of 35 persons. To test the trained CNN model, I have used 70 images (2 from each person). The following for loop was written to predict the probabilities of the 70 images.

I need the predicted probabilities of 70 images (70 * 35) to be assigned to the ndarray `predicted_probabilities`.

```
actual_values_images = []
predicted_values_images = []
predicted_probabilities = np.empty((70, 35), int)

for testImage in test_image_folder: 
    img = folder_path+str(testImage)
    img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(64, 64))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

    result=classifier.predict(img,verbose=0) 
    actual_values_images.append(str(testImage[1:-4]))

    predicted_probabilities = numpy.vstack([predicted_probabilities, result])
    
    predicted_values_images.append(ResultMap[np.argmax(result)])
    predicted_probabilities_images.append(result)
```

But when the above code is run, the shape of the `predicted_probabilities` will be (140, 35). Looks like the same result is vertically appended twice. How can I correctly append the probability values vertically to the 2D array to get a shape of (70, 35)?

Answer (score 1):

A simplest way is to assign results directly to the array.

```
actual_values_images = []
predicted_values_images = []
predicted_probabilities = np.empty((70, 35), int)

for index, testImage in enumerate(test_image_folder):
    img = folder_path+str(testImage)
    img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(64, 64))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

    result=classifier.predict(img,verbose=0) 
    actual_values_images.append(str(testImage[1:-4]))

    predicted_probabilities[index] = result[0] # assign directly to the array
    
    predicted_values_images.append(ResultMap[np.argmax(result)])
    predicted_probabilities_images.append(result)
```

A slightly better way is to collect the results in a list and then convert it to an array. But most efficient way is to process images in batches and then combine the results. Fast sketch:

```
def load2tensor(image_path):
  img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(64, 64))
  img = image.img_to_array(img)
  return img

def batchify(images_list, actual_values, batch_size=32):
  batch = []
  batchNames = []
  batchActual = []
  for img, actual in zip(images_list, actual_values):
    batchActual.append(actual)
    batchNames.append(img)
    batch.append(load2tensor(img))
    if len(batch) == batch_size:
      yield np.vstack(batch), batchNames, batchActual
      batch = []
    continue
  if len(batch) > 0:
    yield np.vstack(batch), batchNames, batchActual
  return

actual_values_images = []
predicted_values_images = []
predicted_probabilities = []

for batch, names, actual in batchify(test_images, actual_values_images, batch_size=32):
  result = classifier.predict(batch, verbose=0)
  predicted_probabilities.append(result)
  # ... rest of the code with actual_values_images, predicted_values_images
```

I'm not sure if this is totally correct, but it should give you a general idea.

Comment: I've probabilities of another model assigned to a 2D array of shape (70,35). I need to average the probabilities of both the models and therefore need this probability values assigned to an array of shape (70,35).

Comment: @DakshilaKamalsooriya hm, in the end all these codes would produce (70, 35). A problem was in the fact that you create an empty array and then append results, so it grows from 70